# NullPointer on long String with jni

Tags: java, string, java-native-interface

I had a problem with java and jni interface. 
I have made a system to connect to some website and print the content and send the content to the jni c++. 
But I have some problem. When I Try to send the BufferedReader in string to the jni I get a java null pointerexception

So Can you help me please ! Thanks ! 
the c++ :

```
#include </jdk1.8.0_191/include/jni.h>
#include "/build/classes/crawlhttpsmemoryc_Crawlhttpsmemoryc.h"





JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_crawlhttpsmemoryc_Crawlhttpsmemoryc_seaubsiteco
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject xtest, jstring xsd) {

   std::string strServiceIp(env->GetStringUTFChars(xsd, NULL));

    std::cout << "du c++" << strServiceIp;

  }
```

And the java :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        String httpsURL = "https://gnu.org";
        URL myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");


        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is));

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String inputLine;
String x = "";
StringBuilder xbuf = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        xbuf.append(inputLine);
        }
 x= xbuf.toString();
    new Crawlhttpsmemoryc().seaubsiteco(x);
```

The stacktrace:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at crawlhttpsmemoryc.Crawlhttpsmemoryc.seaubsiteco(Native Method)
```

Comment: edit your question please, and add a stack trace

Comment: It's not your immediate problem, but your JNI code has a memory leak.  The pointer returned by `GetStringUTFChars()` must be released via `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` before the function returns.

Comment: Just a guess - `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is)` reads the stream so the code after that statement has nothing left to read which results in `x` being an empty string.  Probably should just be `String x = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(is)`.  Where does the exception occur?

Comment: An empty string is not the same thing as `null`, @AndrewS.  Is there some specific way you think that `x` referring to an empty string could cause an NPE to arise in this code?

Comment: No - I realized that too - I updated my previous comment asking where the exception occurs.  As @LhoBen commented, the stack trace is needed.

Comment: @AndrewS the stack trace : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at crawlhttpsmemoryc.Crawlhttpsmemoryc.seaubsiteco(Native Method)

Comment: Please include the Java for your Crawlhttpsmemoryc class.